# Netflix-like competitions

Tags: data-mining

Does anyone know about any competitions or tasks that are similar to the [Netflix Prize](http://www.netflixprize.com/)? It's not only about the money, but also about the dimension of data, the strong link with challenging tasks.

Comment: how is this a programming related question??

Comment: Let's say that this kind of problems cannot be solved by mathematicians.

Comment: Are you looking for said challenging tasks to enter yourself?

Comment: @Shadow: yes, that would allow me to improve my latent DM abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the AI centered conferences run competitions each year which are often open to everyone, e.g.

[Gecco 2009 Competitions](http://www.sigevo.org/gecco-2009/competitions.html)

Comment: Also note Netflix Prize 2 is imminent!

http://www.netflixprize.com//community/viewtopic.php?id=1520

Comment: And also: http://www.tiberius.biz/ausdm09/